# IntelliJ IDEA unable to resolve build.sbt AND no sbt tool window is present

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I've read another answers where you are able to navigate to the sbt tool window and re-build/re-import the project, but in my case there is no sbt tool window at all, although it is present for the newly created projects. Any ideas?

1 - build.sbt highlighted in red

2 - no sbt tool window

3 - sbt tool present in a newly created project

P.S. building project with sbt from the console works perfectly

[image: build.sbt highlighted in red]
[image: no sbt tool window]
[image: sbt tool present in a newly created project]

Comment: The easiest way to fix IntellIJ is to remove .Idea and import project anew as sbt project

Comment: unfortunately, I've already tried this several times with no effect

Comment: Where is your build.sbt file and how exactly do you import project?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was finally able to run the project there were several things wrong -incorrect jdk and jre (I have no idea why is was the way it is), .idea files should be deleted externally

than you will be able to run it correctly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In case anyone will have the same problem**

After two days of trying I was finally able to run the project, steps were:

1. Check that in `Preferences / Build, Execution, Deployment / sbt` you have correct `JRE`
2. Check that in `Preferences / Build, Execution, Deployment / Compiler / Scala Compiler Server` you have correct `JDK`\
3. Check that in `File / Project Structure / Project SDK` you have correct java `SDK`
4. In other than `IntelliJ Idea` code editor delete `.idea` from the project
5. Open `IntelliJ Idea` and if the error is still present - cache invalidation should help - `File / Invalidate Caches / Restart`
   From this point `Idea` will see the project as completely new and you will see the `sbt` tool window.